# VueX/VueJs : Execute code in component after async process

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to display a toast when a async request is finished.
I've implemented this process:

1. Single File Component calls updateUserProfile() actions in my VueX store
2. updateUserProfile() actions makes a outgoing HTTP request on a server using Axios
3. When succeeded, I use a mutation to update the user profile in my store and i would like to show a toast from my single file component.

Problem is that the response object is always undefined in my component. Where is my mistake ?

**Error :**

> profile.vue?a62a:328 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'data' of undefined
>       at eval (profile.vue?a62a:328)

**Store:**

```
/*
  * Action used to fetch user data from backend
  */
updateUserProfile ({commit, state}, userData) {

  // Inform VueX that we are currently loading something. Loading spinner will be displayed.
  commit('SET_IS_LOADING', true);

  axiosBackend.put('/user/profile', userData, { headers: { Authorization: state.authString } } ).then(res => {

    console.log('PUT /user/profile', res);

    // Set user Data in VueX Auth store
    commit('SET_USER_DATA', {
      user: res.data.data
    });

    // Reset is Loading
    commit('SET_IS_LOADING', false);

    return res.data;

  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Reset isLoading
    commit('SET_IS_LOADING', false);
  });

}
```

**Component:**

```
methods: {
    // mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
    ...mapActions([
        'updateUserProfile'
    ]),
    // Function called when user click on the "Save changes" btn
    onSubmit () {
        console.log('Component(Profile)::onSaveChanges() - called');
        const userData = {
            firstName: this.firstname,
        }
        this.updateUserProfile(userData).then( (response) => {
            console.log('COMPONENT', response);
            if (response.data.status === 200) {
                toastr.success("Your profile has been successfully updated.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `user: res.data.data` supposed to be `.data.data`?

Comment: i don't think this is an approach you should be taking, your component should not be aware of any status-codes that need to be checked, that's up to the store to take care of.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

It would be better idea if You trigger the `toast` from the `Vuex` store itself as mentioned below.

```
callAddToCart: ({ commit }, payload) => {
    axiosBackend.put('/user/profile', userData, { headers: { Authorization: 
       state.authString }}).then(response => {
       commit("setLoading", false, { root: true });
       payload.cartKey = response.key;
       commit("setNotification", {
           type: 'success',
           title: `title`,
       });
       commit("ADD_TO_CART", payload);
   });
},
```

and inside mutation you can have a general notification `toast` and you can pass type, message and title as below.

```
setNotification(state, {type, message, title}) {
    state.flash = { 
       type,
       title, 
       message
    }
}
```

NOTE: Do not forget to load `toast` element at the root level in order to display in the UI.

Here is working [example](https://github.com/varit05/chocomama/tree/master/src/store)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, just a question: I use Toastr library and the toastr needs to be displayed from Javascript by invoking toastr.success(...). Where this code needs to be placed ? In my mutation direclty ? But in that case, i don't need to manage a state isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. you can place it inside the mutation directly. However, notification is also a state whenever It will get the value from store. it will be displayed in UI.

Comment: Ok, so it's valid to have a mutation like this one: `SET_NOTIFICATION (state, {type, message, title}){
  switch (type) {
    case "success":
      toastr.success(message);
      break;
    case "info":
      toastr.info(message);
      break;
  }
}`

Comment: you need to pass toast.success as a state from store.

Comment: @wawanopoulos Does it help you?

Comment: No sorry, in your example, you have a fixed component `<vue-snotify />`which is diplayed according the `flash` state. In my case, I don't have any component HTML, it's just triggered from Javascript and I don't know where I need to put my `toastr.success(...)` code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190019/discussion-between-wawanopoulos-and-varit05).